# Modelling employees in Go as a basic OOP exercise

Tags: beginner, object-oriented, go

I am learning Go and have the following working code:

$GOPATH/src/mvctest/main.go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "mvctest/model"
)

func main() {
    // Initialise the data model
    employees := model.NewPeople("Employee")

    // Populate the model
    employees.Add(model.NewPerson("Joe", 99))
    employees.Add(model.NewPerson("Sue", 45))
    employees.Add(model.Person{Name: "Tom", Age: 22}) // break encaps a bit

    // Test retrieval from model
    fmt.Printf("You have %d employees.\n", employees.Count())

    for i := 0; i < employees.Count(); i++ {
        f, err := employees.Person(i)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Unable to get employee %d because %v", i, err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Printf("Employee %d is %s\n", i+1, f)
    }

    // Test error handling for impossible values
    test(employees, -1)
    test(employees, 42)

}

// Tests whether a person can be retrieved using an index value
func test(ppl *model.People, i int) *model.Person {
    p, err := ppl.Person(i)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Unable to get %s %d because %v\n", ppl.Group(), i, err)
        return nil
    }
    return p
}
```

$GOPATH/src/mvctest/model/model.go

```
package model

import (
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

// ------------------------------------------------------

type Person struct {
    Name    string
    hatsize int
    Age     int
}

func (p *Person) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%s aged %d.", p.Name, p.Age)
}

func NewPerson(name string, age int) Person {
    return Person{name, 0, age}
}

// ------------------------------------------------------

type People struct {
    group string
    list  []Person
}

func (ppl *People) SetGroup(g string) {
    ppl.group = g
}

func (ppl *People) Group() string {
    return ppl.group
}

func (ppl *People) Add(p Person) {
    ppl.list = append(ppl.list, p)
}

func (ppl *People) Count() int {
    return len(ppl.list)
}

func (ppl *People) Person(i int) (*Person, error) {
    n := len(ppl.list)
    if i < 0 || i >= n {
        return nil,
            errors.New(fmt.Sprintf("%s index %d is out of range %d-%d.",
                ppl.group, i, 0, len(ppl.list)-1))
    }
    return &ppl.list[i], nil
}

func NewPeople(group string) *People {
    ppl := new(People)
    ppl.group = group
    return ppl
}
```

Output

```
You have 3 employees.
Employee 1 is Joe aged 99.
Employee 2 is Sue aged 45.
Employee 3 is Tom aged 22.
Unable to get Employee -1 because Employee index -1 is out of range 0-2.
Unable to get Employee 42 because Employee index 42 is out of range 0-2.
```

I'd appreciate any comments but a few things that I am uncertain about or which bother me.

- I'm not sure whether defining constructing NewPerson and NewPeople is the right thing to do. I can't have two functions called New in the same file / package and I can't make these into methods of different structs (i.e. different object types) since the caller doesn't yet have an instance to use.
- I'm wondering if there is a simple way to allow iterating using `range` rather than the `for` loop in `main.go`?

Comment: About the second bullet, using the `range` have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35810932/6452829)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a `NewType()` constructor-like function is the idiomatic way in Go. See [Effective Go: Constructors and composite literals](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals). Also relevant: [Effective Go: Package names:](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#package-names)

> The importer of a package will use the name to refer to its contents, so exported names in the package can use that fact to avoid stutter. (Don't use the `import .` notation, which can simplify tests that must run outside the package they are testing, but should otherwise be avoided.) For instance, the buffered reader type in the `bufio` package is called `Reader`, not `BufReader`, because users see it as `bufio.Reader`, which is a clear, concise name. Moreover, because imported entities are always addressed with their package name, `bufio.Reader` does not conflict with `io.Reader`. Similarly, **the function to make new instances of `ring.Ring`—which is the definition of a constructor in Go—would normally be called `NewRing`, but since `Ring` is the only type exported by the package, and since the package is called `ring`, it's called just `New`, which clients of the package see as `ring.New`.** Use the package structure to help you choose good names.

And if you want to iterate over a whole "collection" (e.g. slice, array, map, channel), the [For statements with `range` clause](https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_range) is the clearest way. "Unfortunately" your `People` type does not expose such values, so it's not possible to use `for range` here.

It can still be improved to call `People.Count()` once:

```
for i, count := 0, employees.Count(); i < count; i++ {
    f, err := employees.Person(i)
    // ...
}
```

#### Other improvements

Your `NewPeople()` could be simply written as:

```
func NewPeople(group string) *People {
    return &People{group: group}
}
```

In `People.Person()` it's redundant to call [`errors.New()`](https://golang.org/pkg/errors/#New) and [`fmt.Sprintf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Sprintf), as the [`fmt`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/) package also has an [`fmt.Errorf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Errorf) function doing just that:

```
func (ppl *People) Person(i int) (*Person, error) {
    if n := len(ppl.list); i < 0 || i >= n {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("%s index %d is out of range %d-%d.",
            ppl.group, i, 0, n-1)
    }
    return &ppl.list[i], nil
}
```

Also it's just a matter of taste, but I find it easier to read if you use the `max` index instead of the length (which is `max+1`):

```
if max := len(ppl.list) - 1; i < 0 || i > max {
    return nil, fmt.Errorf("%s index %d is out of range %d-%d.",
        ppl.group, i, 0, max)
}
```

Also it's a good habit for a specific type to be consistent. Either use pointers in all places, or non-pointers. In case of `Person`, you mix both: `People.Add()` expects `Person`, but `People.Person()` returns `*Person`.

Comment: That's a very good point about loop condition optimization. I guess it could be very challenging or impossible for the compiler optimization to do it. So I will pay more attention to that in future. Thanks, just the sort of answer I was hoping for.